# Disabled cookies for my website, I get TokenMismatchException

Tags: laravel

I have disabled cookies for my website and get `TokenMismatchException`. Since I am using sessions file driver and in my form I have `{{ csrf_field() }}` why do I get `TokenMismatchException` when I disable cookies for my website ?

If I inspect the call that was made I can see that the token was sent in post : *token J0Y0t2hj3jjVFMdGCch0apliPqlz1lZlwUc0VqCk*

Answer (score 3):

> why do I get TokenMismatchException when I disable cookies for my website?

Because the CSRF token value in the form needs to be compared to (the) one stored in the session.

If your session is not working without cookies, then of course this will fail.

So decide whether you want to demand cookies for your app to work, or if you want to use less secure ways of transporting the session id (GET/POST – how to configure that within your framework, should be in its documentation.)

Comment: my session driver is set to file, this means that laravel should not use cookies to store session data

Comment: I am not talking about storage of the session data, but passing of the session id between client and server.

Comment: Encrypted data stored in cookies is not a “real” session anyway (IMHO at least; I never understood why certain frameworks see any benefit in that weird mechanism.) “Real” sessions store the data on the server, but then of course need some way to associate stored data with a specific client – and that’s where the _session id_ comes into play. The client has to send the session id it was told by the server _back_ to the server on the next request, so that the server knows which set of stored data belongs to that client. […]

Comment: […] And this session id is usually transported via a cookie. Now if you disable cookies in your browser, the server will not know which session data is associated with the client, and therefor create a new, empty session. This empty session has no CSRF token stored, and therefor there is nothing to compare the CSRF token value send by the form to.

Comment: So if you need your app to work without cookies as well, you need to pass the session id via GET or POST instead. PHP has a default mechanism for that (“trans sid”), that can modify HTML output created by the script accordingly, but I don’t know if that works smoothly with Laravel. Plus, it has possible security implications to send the session id that way.

Answer (score 0):

check your config file(config/session.php) and see if your session driver is cookie. If yes, then change that to something else.
here is the notes: [Laravel's HTTP Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#configuration)

```
file - sessions are stored in storage/framework/sessions.
cookie - sessions are stored in secure, encrypted cookies.
database - sessions are stored in a relational database.
memcached / redis - sessions are stored in one of these fast, cache based stores.
array - sessions are stored in a PHP array and will not be persisted.
```

Comment: in my .ENV SESSION_DRIVER=file

Comment: ok then, if that's the case, you have to pass the client unique id with your request each time though